# Android Webview IMG from string.xml getting exception

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to display an image from a local assets directory on a ICS Android app.

The png is 40.png it's under appname\assets\40.png
The string in string.xml is:

```
 <string name="p40"><img src="file:///android_asset/40.png"/></string>
```

And here is the code I use to load the IMG:

```
              String myhtmlIMG= getResources().getString(R.string.p40);
              webView.loadData(myhtmlIMG,"text/html", null);
```

When I run with this I get an exception:

```
06-11 15:02:04.986: W/System.err(12939):    at libcore.net.http.AbstractHttpInputStream.checkNotClosed(AbstractHttpInputStream.java:68)
06-11 15:02:04.986: W/System.err(12939):    at libcore.net.http.FixedLengthInputStream.read(FixedLengthInputStream.java:41)
06-11 15:02:04.990: W/System.err(12939):    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:244)
06-11 15:02:04.990: W/System.err(12939):    at java.io.BufferedReader.fillBuf(BufferedReader.java:130)
06-11 15:02:04.990: W/System.err(12939):    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:354)
```

However if I was to make an html file in appname\assets\p40.html and include the same  tags I would get the image.  Problem is I must use dynamic png inserted into a html string so this is not a solution.

Is it my quote handling perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

It's an escaping problem. Try using CDATA tags:

```
<string name="p40"><![CDATA[<img src="file:///android_asset/40.png"/>]]></string>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the above doesn't work, escape everything and do Html.fromHTML()

```
<string name="p40">&lt;img src=\"file:///android_asset/40.png\"/&gt;</string>
```

Then

```
          String myhtmlIMG= Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.p40));
          webView.loadData(myhtmlIMG,"text/html", null);
```

-edit-
Just remembered the reason the image isn't loading. You have to override the webview load view to make it able to load from your asset folder. Code in this thread.

[Displaying Android asset files in a WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320288/displaying-android-asset-files-in-a-webview)

Comment: I'm starting to think it's a security issue ... perhaps the webView.loadData is unable to load a image file from my assests ..?

Comment: Yeah I just remembered the reason it wouldn't load.

Comment: So it is some security issue? with ICS?

Comment: Not really a security issue. The WebView just doesn't recognize the asset url by default.