# make android apps with button to external links

Tags: android, jquery, button, hyperlink, android-virtual-device

I want to make a button that links to websites like google.com. I used jquery mobile + eclipse and tried with this Google, it works fine in android virtual device, but when i transferred the app (apk file) to my phone, it doesn't work that way. It just shows me the link with no button like I wanted. Why is that so? What code should I add on the java or xml or androidfest.xml files? PLEASE HELP!!

In addition, I transferred my final apk file through bluetooth instead of using cables. could that be the problem? :/

my MainActivity.java code:

```
package com.example.testing;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");

        return;
    }

}
```

my activity_main.xml:

```
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none" />
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testing"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Note: My heading and footer also did not show as it was supposed to in my real phone. I need help on that too: header, footer, and button functions.

The html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a1/jquery.mobile-1.0a1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a1/jquery.mobile-1.0a1.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/event.css" />
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" data-theme="c" id="home">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <p>
        <a href="https://www.google.com.sg/" rel="external" data-role="button">Google</a>
    <a href="http://www.channelnewsasia.com/" rel="external" data-role="button">CNA</a>
        </p>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer">
    <h4>Bye</h4>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can u share the code here...?

Comment: No that could not be the problem...but we need the code to better understand your problem..!!

Comment: This has nothing to do with the way you put the apk file on your phone.

Comment: ok so that's why I shared the code.

Comment: Look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320288/displaying-android-asset-files-in-a-webview) please.

Comment: i have tried but don't think that's the solution...