# How to change HTML code in WebView (Monodroid)

Tags: c#, android, html, xamarin.android

```
WebView webView = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView1);
webView.HorizontalScrollBarEnabled = false;
webView.LoadUrl("res.htm");
```

How to change some pieces of HTML code in my file and show it with webView without physical file changing?

Comment: You can load the file into a String.. parse that String and change whatever HTML you need, and then set the WebView to that changed HTML string.

Answer (score 0):

You can load html as a string by using this code.

```
var htmlView = new WebView(context);
htmlView.LoadData(htmlMarkup, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Comment: I tried to do this:  


StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(       Assets.Open("res.htm"));
            string webString = reader.ReadToEnd();
            webView.LoadData(webString, "text/html", "utf-8");  



but it didnt work. webView showed me code without style

Comment: Are you trying to load an asset? Check out this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320288/displaying-android-asset-files-in-a-webview