# file://android_asset/www/index.html was not found

Tags: android, jquery

I am new to android programming and I am developing my first apps using eclipse.

I have kept my html and jquery codes inside assets folder.

now this is my code in mainactivity.java

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   // webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient);
    webView.loadUrl("file://android_asset/www/index.html");
}
```

when i installed app on my device and run it,
it says,
webpage not available,
the file at `file://android_asset/www/index.html` may have been moved permanently

plz help me to solve this

Comment: If you recently added this html file in Assets then you should uninstall your app and again install fresh apk built.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5320444/1318946

Comment: possible duplicate of [Displaying Android asset files in a WebView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320288/displaying-android-asset-files-in-a-webview)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
webView.loadUrl("file://android_asset/www/index.html");
```

by

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");   // please see the extra forward slash, they have to be 3.
```